# system command of awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

In the following script, couldn't figure out where to place " for awk inside system(), placing " at end generates a syntax error.

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{
if (($3*100/$2)>=10.00){

    printf system("ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'");

    }
    else
    {
    printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 ; 
    }
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to escape the single quotes here:

```
printf system("ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk \'NR==2{print $2}\'");
```

as otherwise it'd close the single quotes from the outer awk command.

Comment: Using a escape character \ after {print $2} considers " as end of awk and throws a different syntax error.

Comment: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Also have edited the question above to even include the else part.